# strange lines in nginx log

Tags: nginx, amazon-elb

I'm running nginx 1.2.6 behind amazon elb.

Periodically I see the following lines in nginx access.log:

```
10.28.135.252 - - [14/Jan/2013:14:20:07 +0000] "-" 400 0 "-" "-" "-"
10.28.135.252 - - [14/Jan/2013:14:20:07 +0000] "-" 400 0 "-" "-" "-"
10.28.135.252 - - [14/Jan/2013:14:20:14 +0000] "-" 400 0 "-" "-" "-"
10.28.135.252 - - [14/Jan/2013:14:20:14 +0000] "-" 400 0 "-" "-" "-"
10.28.135.252 - - [14/Jan/2013:14:20:18 +0000] "-" 400 0 "-" "-" "-"
10.28.135.252 - - [14/Jan/2013:14:20:48 +0000] "-" 400 0 "-" "-" "-"
```

There are no errors in the error log.
What can it be?

Thanks.

Comment: Is `10.28.135.252` the IP of the server running nginx?

Comment: No. Its most probably the IP of ELB, because health checks originate from the same IP.

Comment: This could be caused by a user/request that has clicked on a link on your website and download some content. If the user cancelled the request halfway the log might generate the 400 0 "-" "-" "-" lines.  This can be simulated by starting a telnet session to your host e.g  `telnet hostname 80` and then `CTRL+D` to terminate the connection prematurely. Keep the log file open using `tail -F /var/log/nginx/yourlogfile.log` while you are testing with telnet. You should not be worried about these warnings though.

Comment: Yes. the simulation worked. I guess this lines are left by ELB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This occurs when a client connects to the web server, but then fails to send a request before disconnecting. It also occurs when a client connects, sends a request with `Connection: Keep-Alive` set, but disconnects before sending another request. In either case, they can be safely ignored.

Comment: Its clear. Thanks. I guess its ELB specific behavior.

Comment: It happens outside of EC2 as well. There's not really anything you can do about it.